# Casting variable into instance of one of two classes

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to cast a variable into one of two classes, so that I can use a method.
What I am doing right now is:

```
var list = new ArrayList<MyObjects>();
var variable = anotherVar;
if (variable instanceof Class1) {
     list.addAll(((Class1) variable).getAllMyObjects);
else {
     list.addAll(((Class2) variable).getAllMyObjects);
}
```

So I know exactly that variable can only be an instance of these two Classes. Is there anything possible to make that code more readible? I was thinking of something like:

```
variable = (Class1 | Class2) anotherVar; // would make it alot more readible
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you extract an interface and have both classes implement the interface? Then you only need to call `getAllMyObjects` once (because the interface defines it).

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for this kind of problem is *interfaces*: define a common interface to be implemented by both classes:

```
interface MyObjectsProvider {
  Collection<MyObjects> getAllMyObjects();
}

class Class1 implements MyObjectsProvider {
  @Override
  public Collection<MyObjects> getAllMyObjects() {
    return ...
  }
}

class Class2 implements MyObjectsProvider {
  @Override
  public Collection<MyObjects> getAllMyObjects() {
    return ...
  }
}
```

Usage could be as simple as:

```
MyObjectsProvider variable = anotherVar;
list.addAll(variable.getAllMyObjects());
```

or if the type is unknown and cannot be constrained to the interface:

```
var variable = anotherVar;
if (variable instanceof MyObjectsProvider) {
     list.addAll(((MyObjectsProvider) variable).getAllMyObjects);
}
```

Comment: Its not possible cause i use xtext and I cant define interfaces myself... Any other solution possible?